# How to unregister SensorEventListener in Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have implemented a small application that displays the y-value of my accelerometer, once as raw data, once low-pass filtered. It runs in a separate thread, to keep my UI responsive.

Now in my UI, when I quit my application, I implemented a standard `onPause()` method:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorThread.interrupt();
}
```

In my Sensor thread, I handle the interrupt, but I am doing something wrong, as the SensorEventListener will not be unregistered. Here is my SensorThread:

```
public class SensorThread extends Thread implements SensorEventListener {
    private Context context;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private long lastUpdate;
    private long startTime;
    private final float RC = 150.0f;
    float accel_y_smoothed = 0.0f;
    private Handler handler;

    public SensorThread(Context context, Handler handler) {
        this.context = context;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void run() {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Gather Sensor data
        if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            float accel_y = event.values[1];

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate > 10) {

                // Filter Sensor data
                float timeInterval = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate;
                //plot_raw.addValue(accel_y, startTime - System.currentTimeMillis());

                float alpha = timeInterval / (RC + timeInterval);
                accel_y_smoothed = alpha * accel_y + (1 - alpha) * accel_y_smoothed;
                //plot.addValue(accel_y_smoothed, startTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putFloat("smoothed_y", accel_y_smoothed);
                bundle.putFloat("raw_y", accel_y);
                bundle.putLong("timestamp", startTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                message.setData(bundle);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        } else {
            stopThread();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    private void stopThread() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

How do I unregister my SensorEventListener properly when I interrupt the Thread?

Comment: Just an thought... Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
that is the code I use when I do GUI-stuff from the background, I can imagine that this could do the trick here also...

Comment: @MartinPfeffer thank you for this idea. I will try if this works. However, I would still be interested in an appopriate solution for my version ;)

Comment: nice, please let me know if it works. :)